# how can I order the results of a query filter?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this line of code in my views that allows me to display a group of items by date (I've also reversed the order so the most recent displays first):

```
currentlinks = Current.objects.order_by('date_added').reverse()[:5]
```

works fine, but however, when I concatenate the `order_by` code with a filter...

```
currentsources = Current.objects.filter(source__exact='bbc').order_by('date_added')
```

why doesn't this doesn't work? poor syntax perhaps, or am I just not understanding how this is supposed to work?

Comment: What doesn't work? The syntax looks correct. Does it give an error, does it produce the wrong data, does it get anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no `Current` objects with a `source` of "bbc", then you will of course get an empty result set. Is that what you mean by *doesn't work*? If not, please post the results you do get.

**Update:** One more thing to try: fire up

```
manage.py shell
```

and then in the shell, evaluate the queryset which is giving the problem.

```
currentsources = Current.objects.filter(source__exact='bbc').order_by('date_added')
```

Then, do the following:

```
from django.db.import connection
connection.queries
```

and this will show the raw SQL which is executed for the queryset. It should help home in on the issue.

Comment: hi Vinay,
it returns the objects, but they are not ordered by date. in fact, i can't tell how they're ordered - seems random (although, I'm sure it's not.)

Comment: So exactly what type is the `date_added` property of your `Current` model?

Comment: date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

Comment: will execute instructions and investigate from there. thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed in your query: if you're trying to reverse the order so that more recent dates appear first, you would use the following syntax:

currentlinks = Current.objects.order_by('-date_added')

The minus sign in front on the field reverses the order. It equates roughly to the following syntax in SQL:

SELECT * FROM current_links ORDER BY date_added DESC

The order_by() should work if you chain it after a filter(), provided that the filter() is valid.